# Java - Как получить модификаторы класса

Tags: java

Есть 2 класса. В первом классе метод main, с которого начинается запуск программы и который должен определять модификаторы 2-го класса. Код 1-го класса:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        Class aClass = t.getClass();
        int mods = aClass.getModifiers();
        if (Modifier.isPublic  (mods))  { System.out.println("public");  }
        if (Modifier.isAbstract(mods))  { System.out.println("abstract");}
        if (Modifier.isFinal   (mods))  { System.out.println("final");   }
    }
}
```

Второй класс:

```
public final class Test {

}
```

При отрабатывании программы все хорошо, вывод правильный "public final". Но стоит объявить класс Test абстрактным, то, конечно, в классе Main полявляется ошибка, т.к. объекты абстрактных классов создавать нельзя. Собственно, вопрос: как преобразовать код класса Main, чтобы можно было получать **любые** модификаторы.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int mods = Test.class.getModifiers();
```